# Taylor series for $\frac{1}{az+b}$ centered at $z=0$ by substitution

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need to find the Taylor series centered at $z=0$ (i.e., the Maclaurin series) for $\displaystyle \frac{1}{az+b}$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b \neq 0$.

I thought it would be good to start out with the geometric series $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}$, $|z|<1$ and then try to manipulate $\displaystyle \frac{1}{az+b}$ to make it look like $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-z}$ in order to figure out what the substitution for $z$ should be.

However, I wasn't able to get past $\displaystyle \frac{1}{az+b} = \frac{1}{b-(-a)z}$ before I got stumped as to what to do next to get it to look like $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-z}$...

Could someone please let me know what I need to do in order to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{b + az} = \frac{1}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{-a}{b} z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \bigg( \frac{a}{b} z \bigg)^{n}, \quad \lvert z \rvert < \dots$$

Comment: @Mattos, that's basically an answer. You should have posted it as such, and I would have accepted and given you points.

Comment: It's alright, I prefer to leave comments so as to try and get the poster to work through the problem themselves after a hint (though in this case I probably gave away too much, so I'll let you figure out what $\lvert z \rvert$ must be less than).

Comment: @Mattos, $|z|<\vert \frac{b}{a} \vert$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is substitution needed?
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{az+b}&=\frac{1}{b}\frac{1}{1+\frac{az}{b}}\\
&=\frac{1}{b}\left(1-\left(\frac{az}{b}\right)+\left(\frac{az}{b}\right)^2-\left(\frac{az}{b}\right)^3+\cdots\right)
\end{align}

Comment: well, technically what you just did is substitution, isn't it?

Comment: @JessyCat I thought that "substitution" meant to explicitly define "u=??", but if you meant to find $x$ such that $c/(1-x)=1/(az+b)$, then you might be right.

Comment: and then $|z|<\vert\frac{b}{a}\vert$ is the radius of convergence?

Comment: @JessyCat You found it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\frac xy = \frac{\frac1b x}{\frac1b y}=\frac{1}{b}\cdot \frac{x}{\frac{y}{b}}$$